# What is 'name' keyword in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please explain this 'name' keyword
What is it?
How we can use it?
Syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle said it is a keyword - that's identifier that has a special meaning.

As opposed to *reserved words*, you can use keywords (including `name`) to name your own objects or variables, but that's **not recommended**. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure name as   --> procedure name is "name"
  2    name varchar2(20);                  --> variable name is "name"
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

---

As of reserved words - for example, `from` is one of them - you can't use them at all:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure from as    --> procedure name is "from"
  2    from number;                         --> variable name is "from"
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /
create or replace procedure from as
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04050: invalid or missing procedure, function, or package name


SQL> create or replace procedure test as  --> procedure name is fixed
  2    from number;                       --> variable name is still "from"
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of
         the following:
         begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
         exists prior external language
         The symbol "begin was inserted before "FROM" to continue.

5/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the sym
<snip>
```

For completeness, you *can* use reserved words if you enclose them into double quotes, but that's really something you should avoid:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure "from" as
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

---

More info in documentation, e.g. [PL/SQL Reserved Words and Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-reserved-words-keywords.html#GUID-9BAA3A99-41B1-45CB-A91E-1E482BC1F927) and [Reserved Words and Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-53E09662-5AD4-4530-8C6B-FF3F7C7430D5)